# CSS works in chrome dev tools and live css editor, but not on wordpress live site

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to add some css to fix rtl of this web page: http://homedoctor.sa/ar/insurance/

I tried the css on chrome dev tool and live css editor, and it seems to work perfectly. However, when I add the same code through wordpress (Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS) it shows no change.

I have tried adding !important but that didn't work either. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnnA5.png)

Here's the css:

```css
.rtl .elementor-7410 .elementor-element.elementor-element-3b979d8f .elementor-heading-title {
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 17px;
}

.rtl .elementor-7410 .elementor-element.elementor-element-18d64e63 .elementor-image-box-content .elementor-image-box-title {
float: right;
}

.elementor-7410 .elementor-element.elementor-element-3b979d8f {
    text-align: center; 
}
.elementor-7410 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5d12ca7f .elementor-heading-title {
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using elementor page builder to create your pages. The thing with elementor is that it's css is pasted in Elementor edit page and not in the Appearance > Customization > Additionoal CSS.

You can add them in the  `Elementor > Navigate to Section > Click on Section where you want to place this > Goto Advanced options in left Elementor Panel > Custom CSS` and paste your CSS over there.

This should solve your problem and can help you edit your pages.

Comment: That solved the problem! Thank you so much :) 
I just want to ask, is this due to the new updates? Because I have around 1300 lines of codes for elementor pages added through the customize widget in wordpress and they somehow work just fine